# iOS - GoogleSignIn sdk integration in Objective-C project using pod is resulting in link error

Tags: ios, cocoapods, linker-errors, google-signin

After integration of GoogleSignIn sdk, i am getting the following link error -

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDSignIn",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in xxx.o
>         objc-class-ref in xxx.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)
>
> I tried the following setting changes but still the issue persists
>   1. framework search path, library search path = $(inherited)     other linker flag = -ObjC
>   2. Added SafarServices.framework, security.framework, systemconfiguration.framework, addressbook.framework, libz.dylib
>   3. build active architecture only = false
>   4. valid architectures = (armv7, arm64, i386, x86_64)
>
> The problem is the binary is getting created with i386, x86_64 architecture after checking with lipo -info command but still this linking coming.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try [manual integration](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/) instead of CocoaPods. It's not difficult and can be more reliable for binary dependencies in my experience.

> ### Add the SDK your Xcode project
>
> 1 Extract the SDK archive you downloaded and copy the following files to your Xcode project:
>
> ```
> GoogleSignIn.bundle
> GoogleSignIn.framework
> GoogleSignInDependencies.framework
> ```
>
> 2 Add `GoogleSignIn.bundle` to your Xcode project's Copy Bundle Resources build phase.
>
> ### Link dependent frameworks to your Xcode project
>
> 1 Link the following frameworks to your Xcode project:
>
> ```
> SafariServices.framework
> SystemConfiguration.framework
> ```
>
> 2 Add the ObjC linker flag to the app target's build settings:
>
> - Other Linker Flags: `$(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC`

This should get you at least far enough to build. Also try cleaning your `DerivedData` folder.

Comment: Thank you Orkoden. I tried the manual integration approach and after compilation i got a couple of "symbol(s) not found for architecture" errors. These got vanished after adding Security.framework, libz1.1.3.tbd. But now i am stuck with this error  "-[__NSDictionaryI gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance". Tried adding google utilities frameworks, addressbook.framework but still no luck.

Comment: In continuation with the above comment just want to highlight that there is no more compilation errors now but app is getting crashed with the stated error msg  "-[__NSDictionaryI gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance".